# Modal form not send data to spring boot controller

Tags: spring-boot, bootstrap-modal

I have a view made with bootstrap modal, but this form not send data to my controller. When print data from console I have only null values. My view is following:
[modal-form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydsrT.png)

My code in the frontend is:

```
<!-- new modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <form th:action="@{/creconocida/addNew}" method="post">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <h5 class="modal-title w-100" id="exampleModalLabel">Nueva
                        Comunidad Reconocida</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Código
                                único</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo"
                            name="codigoN" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">Nombre</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre"
                            name="nombreN" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">Número
                                familias</span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numero"
                            name="numeroN" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Nacionalidad</label>
                        </div>
                        <select class="custom-select" id="nacionalidad"
                            name="nacionalidadN">
                            <option selected>Seleccione...</option>
                            <option value="1">One</option>
                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer ">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-auto">Guardar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Add new method in controller

```
@PostMapping("/addNew")
public String addNew(ComunidadReconocida creconocida) {
    System.out.println("Guardando comunidad "+creconocida.getNam_m());//get only null values
    asentamientoService.addNew(creconocida);
    return "redirect:/creconocida/listar";
}
```

I can create a new entity but I can't send the values ​​entered in the form. How could I do to capture the values ​​and pass them to the controller

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are not indicates to Spring that you want a '@RequestParam'.

```
public String addNew(@RequestParam ComunidadReconocida creconocida)
```